# How do I parse Url into object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have given an url

```
const url = 'http://localhost:3000/?user=123&LEA_CODE=123&RES_PHONE=+77055321767&token=asd'
```

I need to parse it into object.
I tried creating an array using split

```
url.split('/')[url.split('/').length-1].split('&')
```

What I got is array

```
["?user=123", "LEA_CODE=123", "RES_PHONE=+455566", "token=asd"]
```

How do I transform this array into object

```
{
user: 123,
LEA_CODE= 123,
RES_PHONE: +455566,
token: asd
}
```

I think I should use reduce method. But I don't know how

Comment: An array is an object. However you want keys. Why not try `Object.fromEntries(urlArray.map(part => part.split("=")))`?

Comment: Although you might want to remove the leading `?` before manipulating the string.

Comment: If you just want the URL parameters, then use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams). If you want to parse the whole URL, then [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL). Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: yes, I also want to delete '?'